Safe Wallet: "Solidity Compiler Bugs"
Good day
I have created a safe wallet. Out of curiosity I checked the created address on Etherscan. Under "contract" there is a warning on the right that says "Solidity Compiler Bugs". On-click there are a couple of bugs displayed. Is this a concern -- is something wrong with my safe? Thank you!
I am a non-technical person.
The provided bugs are:
FullInlinerNonExpressionSplitArgumentEvaluationOrder (low-severity)
MissingSideEffectsOnSelectorAccess (low-severity)
AbiReencodingHeadOverflowWithStaticArrayCleanup (medium-severity)
DirtyBytesArrayToStorage (low-severity)
DataLocationChangeInInternalOverride (very low-severity) 
NestedCalldataArrayAbiReencodingSizeValidation (very low-severity) 
SignedImmutables (very low-severity)
ABIDecodeTwoDimensionalArrayMemory (very low-severity) 

Edit: I checked other Safe addresses and all I checked have the same altert message. Seemingly this is not something related to my specific address then.

Usually these will be automated warnings, but if you speak to the developers or read trough the comments of the contract they can explain why that potential issue cannot be exploited in this case. For example EmptyByteArrayCopy warning when the contract doesn't copy empty bytes to storage or expand an array. To get the best answer see if they have an engineering channel in discord or similar, they are very legit and good devs are generally accessible. The contracts are also well battletested and I'm sure you could access audits.

These warnings are relative to the Solidity compiler used in Safe contracts, and does not imply any critical vulnerabilities in the code. You should be able to use your Safe in all security :)
Best, Louis
